# Assert that a component can only be used as a child of another component

Tags: javascript, angular

Suppose I have two components, `<child>` and `<parent>`, and I want to assert at runtime that the Child component is used within the Parent component as follows:

```
<parent>
  <child></child>
</parent>
```

How would I do this?  I've tried to inject the parent into the child via the child's constructor and assert its existence, but I am getting cyclic dependency errors because the parent also needs references to the child.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inject the host of the child component with the [following syntax](https://angular.io/api/core/Host):

```
import { Component, Optional, Host, Inject, forwardRef } from '@angular/core';
import { ParentComponent } from './parent.component';

...
export class ChildComponent {
  constructor(@Optional() @Host() @Inject(forwardRef(() => ParentComponent)) parent) {
    console.log("Has valid parent:", !!parent);
   }
}
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tekwkg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fchild.component.ts) for a demo.

---

If you want Angular to throw an exception when the appropriate parent component is not found, remove the `@Optional` decorator:

```
constructor(@Host() @Inject(forwardRef(() => ParentComponent)) parent) {
  console.log("Has valid parent!");
}
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-j1nzfc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fchild.component.ts) for a demo.

Comment: I get an error if I attempt to do this due to a cyclic dependency,  ParentComponent imports ChildComponent as a ContentChild.

Comment: I tried to reproduce the cyclic dependency error in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tekwkg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fparent.component.ts) but it works fine. Is your code different?

Comment: Can you show in the question or in a stackblitz how you get the cyclic dependency problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `element.parentElement.tagName` chain to get the direct parent of the element :

```js
const children = [...document.querySelectorAll('child')];

children.forEach(child => {
  child.addEventListener('click', event => {
    if (event.target.parentElement.tagName.toUpperCase() !== 'PARENT') {
      throw new Error('Child not in parent !');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<parent>
  <child>Click on me to check if I am in my parent</child>
</parent>

<div>
  <child>Click on me to check if I am in my parent</child>
</div>
```

In the case of Angular that would give

```
constructor(el: ElementRef<HTMLElement>) {
  if (el.nativeElement.parentElement.tagName.toUpperCase() !== 'APP-PARENT') {
    throw new Error('Child not in parent !');
  }
}
```