# Host component changing behavior of child component

Tags: javascript, angular

Suppose I have the following component `Child`.

```
@Component({...})
class Child {
  @Input() mySpecialFlag: boolean;
}
```

`Child` can either be used as a stand-alone component, or can be wrapped by a `Special` component, which "scopes" the behavior of `Child`.  When `Child` is used stand-alone, the user can choose to either set `[mySpecialFlag]` to true or false. When `Child` is used within `Special`, I want the `Special` component to force the input `[mySpecialFlag]` to be true, via something like the following:

```
@Component({...})
class Special {
  @ContentChild(Child) child;
  ...
  ngAfterContentInit() {
    this.child.mySpecialFlag = true;
  }
}
```

The issue with the above is that it sets `[mySpecialFlag]` *too late*. I want to be able to set this flag to true before any of the child's lifecycle methods have run, or at least before the child's `ngAfterContentInit` has ran.  Is this possible?

Comment: Could the child component itself set the flag in its constructor when detecting that it is inside of a `SpecialComponent` (as discussed in [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54673021/1009922))?

Comment: It could, but I'm opposed to that because preferably the child component shouldn't have *any* branching logic inside itself that changes its behavior based upon where it is.  It shouldn't have to care about that. All that logic should, in my opinion, exist inside `Special`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the flag in `ngOnInit` of the parent appears to work: the flag is set before `ngOnInit` of the child component.

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.child.mySpecialFlag = true;
}
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xnzf4p?file=src%2Fapp%2Fchild.component.ts) for a demo.

---

An alternative method to access the child component as early as possible is to associate the `@ContentChild` decorator to a getter/setter property, and to set the child flag in the setter:

```
export class ParentComponent {

  private _child: ChildComponent;

  @ContentChild(ChildComponent) get child(): ChildComponent {
    return this._child;
  }
  set child(val: ChildComponent) {
    this._child = val;
    this._child.mySpecialFlag = true;
  }
}
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kcbjxr?file=src/app/parent.component.ts) for a demo. Please note that the private variable `_child` and the getter are not needed to set the flag. I added them in case you need to refer to the child component for other purposes.

Comment: Yeah this seems to work in the stackblitz.  I'm confused though with a few things, maybe you can help me understand them.  First, I thought that content children were not "available" until the parent's AfterContentInit hook?  Second, per this article (https://www.intertech.com/Blog/angular-component-lifecycle/), it says that the parent's AfterContentInit runs *before* the child's AfterContentInit.  However, that's *not* what I'm seeing in your demo.  What gives?

Comment: Quickly adding onto this, it says here (https://angular.io/api/core/ContentChild) that content children are set before AfterContentInit is called, not before OnInit.  So, again, how can we set mySpecialFlag to true here in OnInit?

Comment: I am not sure also why the child is available in the parent `OnInit`. I added to the answer another method to access the child component as soon as its reference is available in the parent.

Comment: Cool, good idea.  I'm still very confused on how the former solution is working, so I am going to keep investigating.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could use ngOnInit method. Refer to this link explaining angular Lifecycle hooks: https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks